# How can I plot this piecewise function?

Tags: plotting, piecewise

How can I plot function $g(x)$ given below:

[image]

The following attempt I have tried does not work and returns errors:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, x > 0}, {0, x = =0}, {-1, x < 0}}]
g[x_?NumericQ] := x^2 f[x - 1]
Plot[g[x], {x, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

[image]

I expect the following output:

[image]

Comment: `Clear[f];f[x_] = Piecewise[{{1, x > 0}, {0, x == 0}, {-1, x < 0}}]`  `==` instead of `=`.  Or using `Sign` instead.

Comment: @cvgmt The function image drawn has errors. When x=1, the image is a segment perpendicular to the x-axis. Isn't the correct image at x=1 and y=0? Is there only one point {1,0} and a dashed line here?

Comment: Use `Plot[g[x], {x, -2, 2}, Exclusions -> x == 1]`, if you do not want a vertical line.  You should not call a result wrong simply because you would like the answer in a different format.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, x > 0}, {0, x == 0}, {-1, x < 0}}];
g[x_] := x^2 f[x - 1]
Plot[g[x], {x, .5, 1.5}, ExclusionsStyle -> Dashed, 
 Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[10], Point[{{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, -1}}], 
   White, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[{{1, 1}, {1, -1}}]}]
```

```
Clear[g];
g[x_] = x^2*Sign[x - 1];
Plot[g[x], {x, .5, 1.5}, ExclusionsStyle -> Dashed, 
 Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[10], Point[{{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, -1}}], 
   White, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[{{1, 1}, {1, -1}}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

We can use `ExclusionsStyle -> {Dashed, AbsolutePointSize[10]}` to style the excluded line and its endpoints without having to know where the discontinuities are.

***Examples:***

```
ClearAll[g, h, s]

g[x_] := x^2 Sign[x - 1] 

pg = Plot[g[x], {x, 0, 1.5}, ImageSize -> 400,
 ExclusionsStyle -> {Dashed, AbsolutePointSize[10]}]
```

[image]

We can post-process to modify/add `Point`s:

```
addPoints = ReplaceAll[p_Point :>
  {Point@({1, 0} # & /@ First[p]), p, White, AbsolutePointSize[7], p}];

addPoints @ pg
```

[image]

```
h[x_] := x^2*Sign[x - 1/2] Sign[1 - x];

addPoints @ Plot[h[x], {x, 0, 1.5}, ImageSize -> 400,
  ExclusionsStyle -> {Dashed, AbsolutePointSize[10]}]
```

[image]

```
s[x_] := Sin[2 Pi x] Sign[1/2 - Sin[2 2 Pi x]];

addPoints @ Plot[s[x], {x, 0, 1.5}, ImageSize -> 400,
  ExclusionsStyle -> {Dashed, AbsolutePointSize[10]}]
```

[image]

**Update:** An alternative way to use `addPoints` is to make it the setting for `DisplayFunction` in `Plot[...]`:

```
Row[
 Plot[#[x], {x, 0, 1.5}, ImageSize -> 400, 
     ExclusionsStyle -> {Dashed, AbsolutePointSize[10]}, 
     DisplayFunction -> addPoints]& /@
   {g, h, s}, 
 Spacer[10]]
```

[image]